# In Adventurer's League, is it possible to keep the Ring of Winter if you manage to acquire it in the Tomb of Annihilation adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league, tomb-of-annihilation

If you manage to

> kill Artus Cimber

and get the Ring of Winter in D&D Adventurer's League, is it possible to buy the ring via treasure points after the adventure? If you can, how many points does it cost?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Not in Adventurer's League.

This is from the Tomb of Annihilation Primer, found [here](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/ToAPrimerv1.pdf). This document is a guide put out by Wizards of the Coast for players and DM intending to take part in Tomb of Annihilation, and lays down the rules of play for this adventure. Do note that this quote is from the DM-only section of that document. Proceed with caution if you're a player.

> Some characters may be tempted to claim ownership of the Ring of Winter and Artus’s prized dagger, Bookmark. As Artus is completely unwilling to surrender these items voluntarily, characters must use force or magic to obtain them. Given Artus’s importance in Faerûn, this spells the end of an adventuring hero’s career.
>
>  Characters involved in facilitating the theft of Bookmark or the Ring of Winter are permanently and irrevocably retired from Adventurers League play—some crimes are beyond forgiveness.

If you take it from him OR help someone else take it from him, your character is immediately and permanently barred from all AL play.

Answer (score 33):

## No, it can't be kept.

During Season 7, the penalty was pretty harsh (permanently and irrevocably retired, as [guildbounty's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/142494/22138) indicates). However:

### Consult the [D&D Adventurers League Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack) for updates.

When Season 8 released, they changed the guidance to be more general and less strict. You can remove it from the character and resume play with that character.

Specifically, you're looking for the **Content Catalog**. On page 5 of v8.07, there is a list.

> #### Items That Were Never Legal for Play
>
> Some items have never been legal for D&D Adventurers League play. Characters that possess these items are automatically retired from play until such time as the items are removed from their character sheets.

*Bookmark* and the *Ring of Winter* are on the list.

**As items you're not allowed to have anyway, they do not have a table assignment, which means they don't have a TCP cost.**